# propiedad map()

Tags: javascript

buenas estoy aprendiendo a programar en javaScript estaba tratando de hacer un ejercicio donde debía ordenar los números de un array y después eliminar los que se repiten lo logre haciendo lo siguiente (lo dejare mas abajo para seguir con  la explicación ), mi duda esta en que no quería usar un bucle si no usar map() para recorrer el array pero no supe como cambiar la posición de los elemento del array  para hacer esta comparación `number.sort()[i] != number.sort()[i-1]` y poder almacenar en un nuevo array solo un valor, la verdad no se se si se pueda si alguien sabe

disculpen si no pude explicarme bien

usando un bucle en vez de map() :

```
var number = [1, 9, 3, 1, 7, 4, 6, 6, 7];

var arr = []
var k = 0;

for( let i = 0; i < number.length; i++){

    if(number.sort()[i] != number.sort()[i-1]){

        arr[k] = number.sort()[i]
        k++;
    }

}

console.log(parseInt(arr.join("")));
```

nota : despues me di cuenta que podia usar set().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te pongo un ejemplo de como haría usando map, aunque te digo que no es la mejor opción debido a que map se utiliza para transformar toda la lista que se va a recorrer y en este caso tu quieres ir elimando datos de esa lista.

```
listaOrdenada = []
number.sort()
number.map(numero => {
    if (listaOrdenada.includes(numero) === false) {
        listaOrdenada.push(numero)
    } 
})
```

Usamos map para recorrer todos los elementos de la lista, y comprobamos si esos elementos existen en la lista ordenada, si no existe se añaden. Y te digo que no me parece buen opción debido a que map devuelve una lista y en este caso devolvería una lista de undefined.

Una mejor opción sería usar filter, ya que esta si esta pensada para eliminar elementos de la lista, te pongo un ejemplo de como sería:

```
number.sort()
number = number.filter((numero,indice) => {return number.indexOf(numero) == indice;})
```

En este caso indexOf nos devuelve el indice del primer elemento que encuentro con el valor número y si es igual al número que estamos comprobando lo añade a la lista en caso contrario lo descarta.

Espero que te sirva.
Saludos.

Comment: entiendo muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

Para recorrer un array también tienes la opción que contempla ecmascript 2015 de usar: `for (let x of collection)`. `x` es una variable que creas para los elementos del array `collection` let collection es un ejemplo.
Es un array en el que voy introducción elementos después de creado.

`let colection = []
collection.push(new Pakiman ('Cauchin', 100, 30))
collection.push(new Pakiman ('Pokacho', 80, 50))
collection.push(new Pakiman ('Tocinauro', 150, 40))
for (let x of colection) {
x.mostrar()}`
En vez de `of` se puede usar `in` todo depende de si necesitamos mostrar el índice de un objeto, valdría con "in"
Si queremos mostrar el objeto al completo, usamos "of"
Y con eso podrías elegir los números a eliminar.